# jCarousel issue with Easylife Switcher extension for Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, ce-1.9.0.1

I use Easylife Switcher extension in my Magento store, everything seems to be fine until click on color change, when I click on the color jcarousel is stop working, I think it is not reinitialize. In product view page i have this error: ***ReferenceError: ProductMediaManager is not defined*** 
I use this script in the media.phtml and a Magento 1.9 version.

```
     jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

            myCarousel = null; // This will be the carousel object




jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        myCarousel = null; // This will be the carousel object




function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel, state) {
    var page = 1;
    jQuery('#jcarousel_gallery_prev').css('visibility', 'hidden');

    if (state == 'init') {
        myCarousel = carousel;
    }
    jQuery('#jcarousel_gallery_next').bind('click', function() {
        carousel.next();
        page++;
        jQuery('#jcarousel_gallery_prev').css('visibility', 'visible');
        jQuery('#jcarousel_gallery_next').css('visibility', (page == 3) ? 'hidden' : 'visible');
        return false;
    });
    jQuery('#jcarousel_gallery_prev').bind('click', function() {
        carousel.prev();
        page--;
        jQuery('#jcarousel_gallery_next').css('visibility', 'visible');
        jQuery('#jcarousel_gallery_prev').css('visibility', (page == 1) ? 'hidden' : 'visible');
        return false;
    });


    jQuery('.product-view .product-img-box .more-views .jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-item').width(<?php echo $thumbX;?>);

};


        jQuery('#jcarousel_gallery_carousel').jcarousel({
            scroll: 1,
            visible:3,
            initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback,
            buttonNextHTML: null,
            buttonPrevHTML: null,
                setupCallback:function(){
                   jQuery('#jcarousel_gallery_carousel.jcarousel-list li').each(function(){
                        jQuery(this).width(103)
                   })
                },
        });
    });


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
jQuery('.cloud-zoom').live('click', function(){
var images = [];

images.push(jQuery('#cloud_zoom').attr('href'));
jQuery('a.cloud-zoom-gallery').each(function(){
images.push(jQuery(this).attr('href'));
});
jQuery.fancybox(
images,
{
'theme' : 'light',
'padding' : 0,
'type' : 'image',
'changeFade' : 0,
'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
'speedIn'       :   400, 
'speedOut'      :   400,
'openEffect' : 'elastic',
'closeEffect' : 'elastic',
'nextEffect' : 'elastic',
'prevEffect' : 'elastic' 
}
);
return false;
});
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you choose to change the full media block when changing the color (or other attribute). When doing this, any js events on the media images need to be reinitialized in order to make them work. This depends heavily on the theme you are using and the level of customization you have.
In the config section `System->Configuration->Easylife Switcher` there is a field called `Js Callback after media change`. You should put here any javascript code you want executed after the media block is changed. In your case you should reinitialize the carousel. [See an explanation of what each config field does in here](https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher/wiki/configuration).

Comment: thank you so much marius, so my entire javascript that exist in a media.phtml should be moved in the Js Callback after media change?

Comment: If you have any js content in the media file that should be executed when the media block is changed. So you don't need to copy it in the config field (in theory).  But you can try it anyway. but I suspect there is some other js error that prevents your js from the media block being executed. Try to remove from the config field anything related to `ProductMediaManager`. Maybe that helps.

Comment: i remove everything from Js Callback after media change, I edit my post and I add there my entire javascript code that exist in the media.phtml maybe you can figure out in this code. Thank you

Comment: I honestly have no idea what could be wrong. The extension is built to work with the default theme and offers support for custom themes through the js callbacks config fields. That's the most I can do for now.

Comment: thank you marius? I try some things for jcarousel in your extension in Js Callback after media change like reload, destroy ...
but nothing works. you have any idea how jcarousel is reinit? I paste here my entire media.phtml file maybe you can test this on your server? http://pastebin.com/LF3ZK0EE

Comment: marius thank you for your answers I solved, i do how you say with some small modifications.

Comment: Glad it turned out fine.

Comment: Can you tell me one more thing if you want, when I select one color for example, the associated product images thumbnails not return the image in the base image, when i click on the small image he goes in one new page ...

Comment: @RobertD. You need to reinitialize the zoomer. It is done from the same config field. And it depends on the zoomer you use (or lightbox)

Comment: i use fancybox and jcarousel, but how can I do this, you have any idea? can yout ake a look here? http://pastebin.com/LF3ZK0EE